# Jackson - Store nested json object as JSONObject

Tags: android, json, jackson

I am deserializing a json object, which contains a nested json object.

```
{
  "id:" 1,
  "name:" "test",
  "settings": {
   "color": "#ff0000"
  }
}
```

Here is my Car class:

```
public class Car {
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private JSONObject settings;

  // id getter/setter...
  // name gett/setter...

  public void setSettings(JSONObject settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  public JSONObject getSettings() {
    return settings;
  }
}
```

I would like to keep settings as a JSONObject and parse it later as I need it. I am also wanting to avoid creating a Settings class (because of how I'm caching my models with Sugar ORM). When I try to deserialize this with Jackson, settings is always returning "{}". How can I do this with Jackson?

UPDATE:

Here is the code that parses Car:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Car car = objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), Car.class);
```

Car may be a nested object inside of something else, so this won't always be called. If I could always call this, this I would already have access to the json object and could just set the Settings object to the Car manually here.

Comment: provide some code on how do you parse these values?

Answer (score 0):

Changing JSONObject to JsonObject seemed to have fixed the problem.

Comment: How you solved it ? Same error even  if I used `JsonObject`. Can't we use `JSONObject` ?