# Jackson: Store nested json object as JSONObject

Tags: java, jackson, json, objectmapper, jackson-databind

This question is duplicate of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865654/jackson-store-nested-json-object-as-jsonobject), Code is used as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);
Car car = mapper.readValue(new File("fileName"), Car.class);
```

But for `settings` as given in the link, value comes as `{}`. How to solve this issue? I want to use nested object as JSONObject.

Comment: Try to use the annotations `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter` [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter) an example of how to use it.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I tried **Example1** from link you provided. But it also sets the rest of field which are not in POJO `Car`. I just wanted object which is under key `setting`( which is `JSONObject`)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you mean *JsonObject* that is standard from Java EE 7 and not *JSONObject* that is in Android.

Even in the link you provide they talk about it.

Than, here is my Car example:

package org.mas.examples.jackson.models;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.json.JsonObject;

public class Car {

    @JsonProperty(value="id")
    private long id;

    @JsonProperty(value="name")
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private JsonObject settings;

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setSettings(JsonObject settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public JsonObject getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setJsonProperty(String key, Object value) {

        if ("settings".equals(key)) {

            System.out.println("Got it " + key + " value: " + value);

            /* JsonObject settings = ....;  create here your JsonObject */

        } else {
            System.out.println(key + " value: " + value);
        }

    }
}
```

If you run a test like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

try {
    Car car = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);

    System.out.println("Load a car: " + car.getName());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You're going to obtain the following result:

```
Got it settings value: {color=#ff0000}
Load a car: test
```

So it work just on *settings* as described in Jackson Annotation [doc](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations):

> @JsonAnySetter: annotation used for defining a two-argument method as
>   "any setter", used for deserializing values of otherwise unmapped JSON
>   properties